# MongoDB: Aggregate the index value in array of objects with element value of 'x'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, indexof

I'm trying to work from this part of the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/

and my use case is almost identical except instead of having an array of values I have an array of objects:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "items" : [
    {x: "one", y: "two", z: "three"}, 
    {x: "four", y: "five", z: "six"},
    {etc...}
]}
```

The example give the following example: `db.inventory.aggregate([{$project: {index: {$indexOfArray: [ "$items", 2 ] }}}]`

The `2` being the search expression to find withing the array expression of `$items`.

My problem is because I am trying to find the index of the object where element y equals myVariableValue. Been trying many different combinations rearranging the syntax but haven't had return anything except -1 which means it was not found.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: id}},
    {$project: {index: {$indexOfArray: [ "$items", {y: myVariableValue} ] }}}
]);
```

Doesn't seem to work and thought it definitely would.

What is the correct search syntax I am looking for to return the correct value of the index? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$indexOfArray` syntax must be like this:

```js
  {
    $project: {
      index: {
        $indexOfArray: [
          "$items.y",
          myVariableValue
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z5xMlAhTFnh)

It would be good, if an example existed for an array of objects in the mongodb docs.

Comment: Yep! This is the correct syntax. I think I actually did try to attempt that combination but I had another problem in my code. The db document had the value I was searching for stored as an int while I was passing it as a string.....